# Como convierto un json a un arreglo bidimensional por javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo un problema con un json, debido a que tengo que transformarlo en un arreglo bidimensional o con este formato [[0,0], [0,0]], de momento solo se hacerlo para arreglos normales, y tambien ocupo saber como se hace con este formato, que en esencia es lo mismo [[0,0]],[[0,0]].

Aqui dejare el codigo de como lo hice para un arreglo normal:

**Javascript**

```
 $(function () {
        var dataTem = [];
        var dataVir = [];
        var dataDef = [];
        var dataCR = [];
        var dataReg = [];
        var tickData = [];


        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../../../../API/hola',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {

                dataTem.push([0,0]);
                dataVir.push([0,0]);
                dataDef.push([0,0]);
                dataCR.push([0,0]); //[[0, 3], [1, 19]]  [[0,12]]
                dataReg.push([0,0]);

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    dataTem.push([key + 1, val.imp_PTemporal]);
                    dataVir.push([key + 1, val.imp_PVirtual]);
                    dataDef.push([key + 1, val.imp_PDefinitivos]);
                    dataCR.push([key + 1, val.imp_PCambioRegimen]);
                    dataReg.push([key + 1, val.imp_PRegularizacion]);
                    tickData.push([key + 1, val.anio + '/' + val.mes]);
                });
            }
        });
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "ArrayOfIXTipoOperacionImportacion":{
      "IXTipoOperacionImportacion":[
         {
            "anio":"2015",
            "mes":"NOV",
            "mesNo":"11",
            "imp_PTemporal":"4626095.64000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPTemp":"-2966880.12000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPTemp":"-39.07401",
            "imp_PTotalTemportal":"11",
            "imp_PVirtual":"3292554.70000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPVirt":"-698600.84000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPVirt":"-17.50372",
            "imp_PTotalVirtual":"47",
            "imp_PDefinitivos":"351483.72000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPDef":"-44040.60000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPDef":"-11.13474",
            "imp_PTotalDefinitivos":"38",
            "imp_PRegularizacion":"0.00000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPReg":"0.00000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPReg":"-100.00000",
            "imp_PTotalRegularizacion":"0",
            "imp_PCambioRegimen":"59518.88000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPCamReg":"27389.00000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPCamReg":"85.24464",
            "imp_PTotalCambioRegimen":"20"
         },
         {
            "anio":"2015",
            "mes":"DIC",
            "mesNo":"12",
            "imp_PTemporal":"5090159.07000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPTemp":"464063.43000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPTemp":"10.03143",
            "imp_PTotalTemportal":"13",
            "imp_PVirtual":"4041906.34000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPVirt":"749351.64000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPVirt":"22.75897",
            "imp_PTotalVirtual":"42",
            "imp_PDefinitivos":"307289.87000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPDef":"-44193.85000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPDef":"-12.57351",
            "imp_PTotalDefinitivos":"33",
            "imp_PRegularizacion":"1970.05000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPReg":"1970.05000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPReg":"196905.00000",
            "imp_PTotalRegularizacion":"2",
            "imp_PCambioRegimen":"34533.54000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPCamReg":"-24985.34000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPCamReg":"-41.97885",
            "imp_PTotalCambioRegimen":"9"
         },
         {
            "anio":"2016",
            "mes":"ENE",
            "mesNo":"01",
            "imp_PTemporal":"7259696.91000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPTemp":"2169537.84000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPTemp":"42.62220",
            "imp_PTotalTemportal":"15",
            "imp_PVirtual":"3098137.88000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPVirt":"-943768.46000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPVirt":"-23.34959",
            "imp_PTotalVirtual":"43",
            "imp_PDefinitivos":"402000.83000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPDef":"94710.96000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPDef":"30.82137",
            "imp_PTotalDefinitivos":"48",
            "imp_PRegularizacion":"0.00000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPReg":"-1970.05000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPReg":"-100.00000",
            "imp_PTotalRegularizacion":"0",
            "imp_PCambioRegimen":"87980.27000",
            "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPCamReg":"53446.73000",
            "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPCamReg":"154.76760",
            "imp_PTotalCambioRegimen":"8"
         }
      ],
      "_xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
      "_xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   }
}
```

Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo traértelo y parsealo a un objeto para poder trabajarlo:

```
success: function (data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data)
}
```

El resto de la pregunta es que no lo comprendo, ¿Podrías explicarlo de otra forma?..

Comment: basicamente, quiero transformar los valores que mando a llamar del json a un arreglo bidimensional, o arreglo de arreglos, como este formato [[0,0], [0,0]], con el push() o de cualquier otra forma.

Comment: Y no puedes hacer una asignación similar a esta:
`miarray = elarrayorigen[0];`

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo bien el concepto

Comment: Es como quitarle un nivel a tu array ¿no es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: no, quiero agregar uno, un array normal es asi [0,0], yo lo que espero es esto [[0,0]]

Comment: Pues entonces
`myarray.push(arrayorigen)`

Comment: lo hice, pero sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo tu código hice el siguiente ejemplo, lo que pasa es que en el `json` la información que estas tomando en el ciclo esta en el nivel `jsonData.ArrayOfIXTipoOperacionImportacion.IXTipoOperacionImportacion` del `json`, no estoy segura si es lo que necesitas, pero puedes revisarlo para ver si te puede servir de algo, saludos.

```js
 var jsonData = [];

 $(document).ready(function() {
   jsonData = {
     "ArrayOfIXTipoOperacionImportacion": {
       "IXTipoOperacionImportacion": [{
         "anio": "2015",
         "mes": "NOV",
         "mesNo": "11",
         "imp_PTemporal": "4626095.64000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPTemp": "-2966880.12000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPTemp": "-39.07401",
         "imp_PTotalTemportal": "11",
         "imp_PVirtual": "3292554.70000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPVirt": "-698600.84000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPVirt": "-17.50372",
         "imp_PTotalVirtual": "47",
         "imp_PDefinitivos": "351483.72000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPDef": "-44040.60000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPDef": "-11.13474",
         "imp_PTotalDefinitivos": "38",
         "imp_PRegularizacion": "0.00000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPReg": "0.00000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPReg": "-100.00000",
         "imp_PTotalRegularizacion": "0",
         "imp_PCambioRegimen": "59518.88000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPCamReg": "27389.00000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPCamReg": "85.24464",
         "imp_PTotalCambioRegimen": "20"
       }, {
         "anio": "2015",
         "mes": "DIC",
         "mesNo": "12",
         "imp_PTemporal": "5090159.07000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPTemp": "464063.43000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPTemp": "10.03143",
         "imp_PTotalTemportal": "13",
         "imp_PVirtual": "4041906.34000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPVirt": "749351.64000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPVirt": "22.75897",
         "imp_PTotalVirtual": "42",
         "imp_PDefinitivos": "307289.87000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPDef": "-44193.85000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPDef": "-12.57351",
         "imp_PTotalDefinitivos": "33",
         "imp_PRegularizacion": "1970.05000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPReg": "1970.05000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPReg": "196905.00000",
         "imp_PTotalRegularizacion": "2",
         "imp_PCambioRegimen": "34533.54000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPCamReg": "-24985.34000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPCamReg": "-41.97885",
         "imp_PTotalCambioRegimen": "9"
       }, {
         "anio": "2016",
         "mes": "ENE",
         "mesNo": "01",
         "imp_PTemporal": "7259696.91000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPTemp": "2169537.84000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPTemp": "42.62220",
         "imp_PTotalTemportal": "15",
         "imp_PVirtual": "3098137.88000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPVirt": "-943768.46000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPVirt": "-23.34959",
         "imp_PTotalVirtual": "43",
         "imp_PDefinitivos": "402000.83000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPDef": "94710.96000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPDef": "30.82137",
         "imp_PTotalDefinitivos": "48",
         "imp_PRegularizacion": "0.00000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPReg": "-1970.05000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPReg": "-100.00000",
         "imp_PTotalRegularizacion": "0",
         "imp_PCambioRegimen": "87980.27000",
         "diferenciaMesAnteriorIMPCamReg": "53446.73000",
         "porcentajeDiferenciaIMPCamReg": "154.76760",
         "imp_PTotalCambioRegimen": "8"
       }],
       "_xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
       "_xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     }
   }

   //console.log(jsonData.ArrayOfIXTipoOperacionImportacion);

   correrEjemplo();

 });

 var dataCR = [];
 var dataReg = [];
 var tickData = [];
 var dataTem = [];
 var dataVir = [];
 var dataDef = [];

 function correrEjemplo() {

   dataTem.push([0, 0]);
   dataVir.push([0, 0]);
   dataDef.push([0, 0]);
   dataCR.push([0, 0]); //[[0, 3], [1, 19]]  [[0,12]]
   dataReg.push([0, 0]);

   $.each(jsonData.ArrayOfIXTipoOperacionImportacion.IXTipoOperacionImportacion, function(key, val) {
     dataTem.push([key + 1, val.imp_PTemporal]);
     dataVir.push([key + 1, val.imp_PVirtual]);
     dataDef.push([key + 1, val.imp_PDefinitivos]);
     dataCR.push([key + 1, val.imp_PCambioRegimen]);
     dataReg.push([key + 1, val.imp_PRegularizacion]);
     tickData.push([key + 1, val.anio + '/' + val.mes]);
   });

   imprimirArreglos();
 };

 function imprimirArreglos() {
   console.log('Valores para dataTem');
   $.each(dataTem, function(key, val) {
     console.log(val);

   });
   console.log('Valores para dataVir');
   $.each(dataVir, function(key, val) {
     console.log(val);

   });
   console.log('Valores para dataDef');
   $.each(dataDef, function(key, val) {
     console.log(val);

   });
   console.log('Valores para dataCR');
   $.each(dataCR, function(key, val) {
     console.log(val);

   });
   console.log('Valores para dataReg');
   $.each(dataReg, function(key, val) {
     console.log(val);

   });
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es modificar la propiedad IXTipoOperacionImportacion. lo puedes hacer así.

```
 const result = [];
 IXTipoOperacionImportacion.forEach(x => {
     result.push(Object.values(x))
 }
```

Object.values(x) lo que hace es crear un array con todos los valores de un objeto